# Flatten then map object to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an object that needs to be mapped into array with the key as a property. The object looks like:

```
{
 Cat: {
   value: 50
 },
 Dog: {
   value: 80
 }
}
```

I need to convert this to:

```
[
 {
    animal: 'Cat',
    value: 50
 },
 {
    animal: 'Dog',
    value: 80
 }
]
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I have tried

```
 const animalArr = Object.entries(AnimalObj);
```

But am unsure on next step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const AnimalObj = {
  Cat: {
    value: 50
  },
  Dog: {
    value: 80
  }
};

const result = Object.entries(AnimalObj)
  .map(([animal, { value }]) => ({ animal, value }));

console.log(result);
```

Iterate through all the entries of the `AnimalObj` with `Object.entries` and construct a new object out of each entry with `map`.

---

The `map` part in the answer might look a bit complicated.

```
([animal, { value }]) => ({ animal, value })
```

It actually has two parts,

- argument destructuring

  The `Object.entries` returns an array of key and its corresponding value as arrays. In your case, `console.log(Object.entries(AnimalObj))` would have printed

  ```
  [ [ 'Cat', { value: 50 } ], [ 'Dog', { value: 80 } ] ]
  ```

  We pass each and every array in to `map` and `[animal, { value }]` extracts the first string in the individual arrays in `animal` and since the second one, the value, is an object, we destructure it and get only the `value` out of it.
- Object construction

  Now that we have all pieces needed to construct our objects, `animal` and `value`, we use the short hand notation to construct objects with `{ animal, value }`. That basically creates an object with the keys `animal` and `value` with the values of the actual variables against them.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const data = {
 Cat: {
   value: 50
 },
 Dog: {
   value: 80
 }
};

const out = Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => {
  return {
    animal: key,
    ...value
  };
});

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to obtain an array of key value tuple and then using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) transform this array to the desired shape.

```js
const 
  dataObj = { Cat: { value: 50 }, Dog: { value: 80 } },
  dataArr = Object.entries(dataObj).map(([animal, { value }]) => ({ animal, value }));

console.log(dataArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

First use the `Object.entries()` method to convert `key-value` pairs in the object into an array, then use destructuring with the `Array#map` method as follows:

```js
const input = { Cat: {value: 50 },Dog: { value: 80 } };

const output = Object.entries( input )
.map(([animal, value]) => ({animal, ...value}));

console.log( output );
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to flatten it in a separate step. Just map it directly:

```js
AnimalObj = {
 Cat: {
   value: 50
 },
 Dog: {
   value: 80
 }
} 


 const animalArr = Object.entries(AnimalObj).map(([ key, value ]) => ({ animal: key, value: value.value }));
 console.log(animalArr)
```